# Visual Studio 2017 import Cocos2D project

Tags: visual-studio, cocos2d-x, visual-studio-2017, cocos2d-x-3.0

First of All, I use the "cocos new ..." command to create a new cocos2d project using the cpp language. And then i click the CarGame/proj.win32/CarGame.sln to open it in visual studio 2017, but i got the full screen errors.

Could you tell me what are wrongs?
There are the screen captures:
[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: which version of `c++` 11 or 14, cocos2d-x support `c++11` ?

Answer (score 0):

The issue is that some data type that exist in Cocos2d-x and somewhere else in the header files the compiler has seen.

All files of Cocos2d-x exist in `cocos2d` namespace so prepend `cocos2d` to use cocos2d-x files instead of `using` directive for `cocos2d` namespace.

so remove `USING_NS_CC` micro from the top of implementation file.